# how to create a directory with getDir()

Tags: android

I don't understand what should be the context when I want to create a directory in internal memory using `context.getDir()`. How can I get this context object.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a subclass of [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). You get your `Context` from `Activity` or a subclass of it. You have to pass your `Context` when initializing a class that isn't a subclass of `Context` or `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Activity` is a `Context`.